# xml tag optional with vba excel

Tags: xml, excel, vba

I would like to optionally show a parameter under a specific condition in my worksheet. I have these data :

orange 1 
apple 2

I used the "Source" from the Developer ribbon, to make an xml map that associate with the parameters' values.

Thus I generate the following tree:

```
<orange>1</orange>
<apple>2</apple>
```

However, the apple value is optional. Sometimes it will not appear in my table. As a result I have the following problem:

```
<orange>1</orange>
 <apple>
```

which is not of course an accurate xml file. How can I overcome this? I m using the following macro to load the values and generate the xml.

```
Sub GenerateXML()
    Dim nameOfFile As String
    nameOfFile = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "sample.xml"

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAsXMLData Filename:=nameOfFile, _
    Map:=ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("my_Map")
End Sub
```

It's the first time I implement this and it took me a while to figure out how to generate the xml tree correctly. Should I somehow adjust my subroutine to make this optional?

Comment: Cannot reproduce this behavior. But also your first `XML` is not accurate since it lacks the root element. Please do `Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.XmlMaps("my_Map").Schemas(1).XML` and show what it prints.

Comment: Yes I can because I import the xml file I want to have in the beginning. But the problem is that from this xml file I want to delete one child if condition (a certain cell is empty)